# Two sparrows fly to the point halfway between their nests. In a head/tailwind, one arrives a minute later than the other.

Tags: puzzle

Julia and Heiko are two enthusiastic caching sparrows. Therefore, when a new cache is published nearby, they both leave their nests immediately. The cache hiding place is located exactly on the midpoint of the line joining their two nests. Heiko lives to the east and Julia to the west of the hiding place.
In the absence of any wind, both can fly at a speed of 60 km/h . However, on this day, there is a strong wind from the east, blowing with a speed of 44 km/h. This causes Julia's arrival to be one minute later than Heiko, whom, by this time, is already on his way back to his nest which is located at N 52° 30.098 E 13° 22.547.
The question is where is the midpoint?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Is there a question here?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3446411/edit) to add details.

Comment: Sorry guys. The question is where is the midpoint?

Comment: Gerry9999, I will be more blunt than @Blue - Most of us don't enjoy just doing your homework for you.  However, many of us enjoy _teaching_ or giving _hints_ on how to do homework.  That's why you need to show us some effort first...

Comment: Thanks for your response and I wish it was my homework but at 74 years old I can't remember back that  far.  It's actually a Geocaching puzzle in Berlin called Gegenwind GC1VYR7.  I have tried to solve using https://www.symbolab.com/solver/algebra-calculator and y=mx+c but I really don't have a clue. So it's over to  you I am at you mercy. Greetings from Ireland Gerry  Needless to say I can work out the final coordinates if I could find the distance traveled by Keiko.

Answer (score 0):

Gerry: sorry for being blunt and presumptious about this being homework...  :(

Anyway, let $x$ km be the distance from either nest to the midpoint.  Heiko is flying at $60+44 = 104$ km/h and Julia at $60-44 = 16$ km/h.  So Heiko got there at time $x/104$ (hr) and Julia got there at time $x/16$ (hr).  We are given that Julia is late by one minute, i.e.

$${x \over 104} + {1 \over 60} = {x \over 16}$$

which [solves to](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bx+%5Cover+104%7D+%2B+%7B1+%5Cover+60%7D+%3D+%7Bx+%5Cover+16%7D) $x = {52 \over 165}$ km.